# When i try to install Hive 2.0 i get a multiple SLF4J bindings and that Hive metastore database is not initialized

Tags: maven, hadoop, hive

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.
I tried to install hive with hadoop in a linux environment following this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/es/hive/hive_installation.htm). Hadoop is installed correctly but when i try to install hive i get the following output in my shell:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/phd2014/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/phd2014/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/phd2014/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/phd2014/hive/lib/hive-common-2.0.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/phd2014/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive metastore database is not initialized. Please use schematool (e.g. ./schematool -initSchema -dbType ...) to create the schema. If needed, don't forget to include the option to auto-create the underlying database in your JDBC connection string (e.g. ?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true for mysql)
```

In my ~/.bashrc file y put the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export YARN_HOME=/home/phd2014/hadoop
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/home/phd2014/hadoop/etc/hadoop
export HIVE_HOME=/home/phd2014/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

I also export the variables HADOOP_HOME and HIVE_HOME inside the **.profile** file

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35655306/hive-installation-issues-hive-metastore-database-is-not-initialized) didn't work for me, i also run the command to create the Schema but it failed : `schematool -dbType derby -initSchema`

I have one more thing that i think it could help and is to modify the pom.xml file to avoid the multiple SLF4J bindings, but i can't find it. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695848/maven-location-of-pom-xml-file) but i didn't find it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [running hive 0.12 with error of slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050820/running-hive-0-12-with-error-of-slf4j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i try to install hive 2.0.0 i got the error that i posted, but if i install the version 1.2.1 instead it works fine, just by setting the environment variables and creating the `/user/hive/warehouse directory` in the HDFS. It must be a bug of the new version. My recommendation is to install the version 1.2.1 instead of the 2.0.0

Answer (score 2):

SLF4J is a logging API. It will dynamically bind to an implementation but it expects that there will only be one present. In your case it appears that you have three jars that provide an SLF4J implementation; hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar, log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar.

hive-jdbc-2.0.0-standalone.jar appears to be a "shaded" jar - it includes the classes from multiple third party jars, including the contents of log4j-slf4j-impl. I am guessing that this is what SLF4J actually selected since it was the first one found.

The issues is that you are somehow including jars that the standalone jar has already incorporated. Normally with a standalone jar everything you need should already be in that jar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer rgoers, you clarified some of my doubts. I think i could decide which jar to use in my pom.xml file, as is explained in this link [link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings) , but my problem is that i couldn't find my pom.xml.